# undefined method `Py_IsInitialized' for RubyPython::Python:Module

Tags: python, ruby, gollum-wiki

I'm attempting to use Gollum on an Ubuntu server to serve up markdown pages but am receiving the following error whenever I attempt to highlight any syntax.

```
undefined method `Py_IsInitialized' for RubyPython::Python:Module
```

Stack Trace:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.5.3/lib/rubypython.rb in start
  return false if RubyPython::Python.Py_IsInitialized != 0

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pygments.rb-0.2.3/lib/pygments/ffi.rb in start
  RubyPython.start

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pygments.rb-0.2.3/lib/pygments/ffi.rb in highlight
  start unless pygments
```

Comment: what python version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have these packages installed: '**python-pygments**' and '**python-dev**'.

Comment: Needs python-pygments and python-devel on Fedora